# How to redirect ASPpage.asp?id=x to PHPpage.php?id=x

Tags: php, asp-classic

I have a dynamic news website written in ASP now I would like to change to PHP server which doesn't support ASP page.
I have page like **somepage.asp?id=x** now how can I redirect the page to **somepage.php?id=x**
and still keep my old visitors pointing the asp page but it will return the same query result in PHP.
Example: If my visitor point to this page
**www.someweb.com/ASPpage.asp?id=100**
they should be redirected to **www.someweb.com/PHPpage.php?id=100**

thanks in advance

Comment: Does your server support Apache HTAccess and `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: Yes it does have, it uses cPanel

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect pages in ASP Classic, like:

```
<%
    Response.Redirect "PHPPage.php?" & Request.QueryString
%>
```

Also, if your php files will have the same filenames as your asp files, then you can use something like that and put it all yor asp pages...

```
<%
    Response.Redirect Replace(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"),".asp",".php") & "?" & Request.QueryString
%>
```

Hope this helps...

EDIT:

I realized that you will be trying to execute an asp page in a php server which is not supporting ASP? If this is the case, maybe you can add new mime-type to your server and set **.asp** files work as **.php**. Sorry I am not a server-side-control expert but thats the idea and my 5 cents.

Comment: Thank you for the post, but I am not able to opem ASP page in the new server as it doesn't support ASP page. It will just give me 404 error page not found. how to catch this error and redirect to PHP page.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, you have Apache's HTAccess and `mod_rewrite` available to you.

Set up your `.htaccess` file to contain the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ASPpage\.asp?id=(.*)$ PHPpage.php?id=$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score -1):

asp is a microsoft technology and php is open source
so it is not possible unles you change the server port number of php. 
 then redirect to the full address with port number to run the php file

Comment: You do not seem to have understood the question.